# Applying two or more mutexes to a section of code

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex, deadlock

I'm studying mutexes and deadlocks in c++ pthreads from http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

I understood them but i stacked at a point. I didn't understand what is the problem of the below code. Can you explain it with simple and clear words please? I quoted from this site:

Mutex Deadlock: ... Be careful when applying two or more mutexes to a section of code. If the first pthread_mutex_lock is applied and the second pthread_mutex_lock fails due to another thread applying a mutex, the first mutex may eventually lock all other threads from accessing data including the thread which holds the second mutex. The threads may wait indefinitely for the resource to become free causing a deadlock. It is best to test and if failure occurs, free the resources and stall before retrying.

```
01  ...
02  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_1);
03  while ( pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex_2) )  /* Test if already locked   */
04  {
05     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_1);  /* Free resource to avoid deadlock */
06         ...
07     /* stall here   */
08     ...
09     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_1);
10  }
11  count++;
12  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_1);
13  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_2);
14  ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem with that code? It looks more like it's supposed to be an example of how to avoid the described problem.

Comment: I think that the code is correct but I didn't understand what it says in sentences, his sentences are so complex, thus i thought that the code contains some problem.

Comment: #Mike Seymour , I didn't understand anything from this sentence : "If the first pthread_mutex_lock is applied and the second pthread_mutex_lock fails due to another thread applying a mutex, the first mutex may eventually lock all other threads from accessing data including the thread which holds the second mutex. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially if you need two mutexes to perform a task, `mutex_1` and `mutex_2`, if `thread_A` grabs `mutex_1` and `thread_B` grabs `mutex_2`, they are stuck in a deadlock because they are both waiting for the other mutex to become available, but they never will because the other is waiting too.

That is why you typically enforce an order that mutexes can be acquired. For example, you must acquire `mutex_1` before attempting to acquire `mutex_2`. That way you can't have `mutex_2` without first having `mutex_1`, so there is no chance to cause a deadlock.

```
     Thread_A                Thread_B
        |                       |
        |                       |
   lock(mutex_1)                |            // Thread_A got mutex_1
        |                       |
        |                  lock(mutex_2)     // Thread_B got mutex_2
        |                       |
        |                       |
  trylock(mutex_2)              |            // Thread_A wants mutex_2
        |                 trylock(mutex_1)   // Thread_B wants mutex_1
        |                       |
```

Due to the timing, these threads are now at a deadlock. Both are waiting for a mutex that they will never get, because the other thread won't unlock the mutex it is holding until it finishes its work.

In your code example, note that the first thing they do is lock `mutex_1`. They then spin on `mutex_2` until that comes available. This is enforcing the order `mutex_1` then `mutex_2`.

Comment: Assuming all threads always try to acquire the mutexes in the order `1` then `2` as your code shows, yes it should be safe from deadlocks.

Comment: IN this example, more than one mutex are applied to a section of code. What the author means that by saying "... and the second pthread_mutex_lock fails due to another thread applying a mutex ... " Could you explain what this sentence means in simple words?

Comment: I think i understand, you explain a possible case of deadlock, more than one thread may cause deadlock in the figure you give. IN order to avoid this bad scenario, we should enforce using threads with an order. My example exactly did this, am i right? This task enforces locking mutex1, then mutex2, respectively.. Similarly, i can write a task which enforces locking mutex2, then mutex1 respectively. Then thread 1 executes task1, thread2 executes task2 with no possibility of deadlock.

Comment: Sorry, my example " This task enforces locking mutex1, then mutex2, respectively.. Similarly, i can write a task which enforces locking mutex2, then mutex1 respectively. " causes deadlock. HOwever, if more than one thread executes one of these tasks, there will be no deadlock

Answer (score 1):

If you lock one mutex, then wait for the second, the first is still locked, so no-one else can get it while you wait. That's quite bad, so maybe unlock the first mutex while you wait. The code shows how to do that.

If another thread has the mutex you're waiting for, and needs your mutex (which it shouldn't, unless the design is messed up), then that's very bad - both threads will wait for ever, causing a "deadlock" - and you'll definitely need to unlock the first while you wait.

But in that case, you should fix it properly (as the next section describes) - always lock the two mutexes in a well-defined order.

Comment: Think that a similar situation, a thread locks mutex1, then locks mutex2. Then is it safe both of these : "firstly unlock mutex1 then unlock mutex2" and "firstly unlock mutex2 then unlock mutex1" ?

Comment: @metis Provided the initial order of mutex acquisition is correct, the order that you unlock the mutexes wouldn't matter.